# Is there a way to list out all the object classes in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to list the classes of all objects in my environment? I tried

```
asd <- iris
sapply(ls(), function(x) class(x))
##         asd 
## "character"
```

but what I want is

```r
##          asd 
## "data.frame"
```

I am assigning the `iris` data set to the name `asd` and want its class, but my code is returning `"character"` instead of `"data.frame"`.

When we have `N` objects in our environment, we should see how many objects there are and their classes.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for:

```
lapply(mget(ls()), class)
```

Comment: Can we convert this to a dataframe. I tried with ````unlist(lapply(mget(ls()), class))````

Comment: `x <- lapply(mget(ls()), class)`
`data.table(object=names(x) , class = x)`

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for `mget(ls())`. Use `eapply` to obtain the result directly:

```r
x <- double()
m <- matrix()
l <- list()
cc <- eapply(environment(), class)
cc
```

```
$x
[1] "numeric"

$l
[1] "list"

$m
[1] "matrix" "array"
```

If you want a data frame, then you can do:

```r
data.frame(name = names(cc), class = I(unname(cc)))
```

```
  name        class
1    x      numeric
2    l         list
3    m matrix, ....
```